# How to encode video for Sony Vegas (version 7)?

Tags: video, encoding, sony-vegas, xvid

I have a video in XviD format that won't load in Vegas.  (I tried using FourCC changer but that didn't work.)  Then I tried using ffmpeg to encode in (forgot codec name, something like H-242 or something).  Didn't work.

How can I encode a video so that Sony Vegas 7 will load it?

Comment: H.264 (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H264) maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encoded to WMV using ffmpeg via WinFF.  It worked.

Answer (score 0):

After a quick scan around the net, I have found that Vegas 7 does not support Xvid or DivX out if the box. There should be two soulutions

1. Install a codec into Vegas so it can read it.
2. use [tmpgenc](http://www.tmpgenc.net/en/index.html), to convert the AVI file to mpeg1 compression.

Normally I would just recommend [FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) but someone else on a video forum has specifically recommended tmpgenc for the job.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using Super Converter for over a decade.

http://www.erightsoft.com/hawel.php

Install then convert to whatever you wish. I usually go with .mp4 or .avi formats.